# initComponent vs constructor when defining an object

Tags: extjs4, extjs

When should I be using `initComponent` compared to `constructor` ?

I have been using initComponent to extend my objects, but looking at the docs for Ext.define is see them using constructor all over then place. what is the difference?

compare:

```
Ext.define('My.app.PanelPart2', {
    extend: 'My.app.Panel',
    constructor: function (config) {
        this.callSuper(arguments); // calls My.app.Panel's constructor
        //...
    }
});
```

to

```
Ext.define('My.app.PanelPart2', {
    extend: 'My.app.Panel',
    initComponent: function (config) {
        Ext.apply(this, config);
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

I am aware of the fact that some components don't init ( Im looking at you `Ext.data.Store` ), which leads me towards leaning towards only over writing the constructor, as that should be universal.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`constructor` is OOP standard for initializing objects instances and is available in every ExtJS class (everything created by `Ext.define`).

`initComponent` is ExtJS extension for initializing components - classes that extends `Ext.Component`. It uses templated method pattern and enables some standard initialization steps before and after your custom component init. Something like this:

```
Ext.Component.constructor() {
    - init events
    - apply config
    - create plugins
    - ...
    - your custom component initialization (initComponent)
    - ...
    - init plugins
    - etc.
}
```

My best pratices are to use `initComponent` whenever I'm creating custom component and `constructor` only for generic classes.

Comment: hello , this definition still holds right now? Use version 3 of Extjs . Its definition can still be used ? I could still pass me some links for me to study on InitComponent ? I am grateful for the help.